# Python Pandas - what is best way to store pearson correlation values stored in as pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

What is best way to store pearson correlation values as a pandas dataframe.

Correlation is calculated as below

```
Correlation = df.corr()
```

But I want to store the output as dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The output *is* a dataframe.

The docstring in version 0.22 says:

Compute pairwise correlation of columns, excluding NA/null values

```
Parameters
----------
method : {'pearson', 'kendall', 'spearman'}
    * pearson : standard correlation coefficient
    * kendall : Kendall Tau correlation coefficient
    * spearman : Spearman rank correlation
min_periods : int, optional
    Minimum number of observations required per pair of columns
    to have a valid result. Currently only available for pearson
    and spearman correlation

Returns
-------
y : DataFrame
```